# Cannot create a Table in database

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm writing an simple form in PHP that get input and insert it to database, I had succeeded in creating a database, but not a table. I use Xampp for the database. 
Here is my code for creating a table:

```
 mysqli_select_db($DBconnect, $DBname);
        $TableName = "Bugtrack";
        $SQLstring = "SHOW TABLES LIKE ' " . $TableName . "' ";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBconnect, $SQLstring)) {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0) {
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                $SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE" . $TableName . "(BugID SMALLINT 
                        . NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        . Game VARCHAR(10), Version VARCHAR(5),
                          Platform VARCHAR(10), Frequency VARCHAR(5), 
                          proposed_solution TINYTEXT)";
                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBconnect, $SQLstring)) {
                    $QueryResult = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    if ($QueryResult === FALSE) {
                        echo "<p>Unable to create the table.</p>"
                        . "<p>Error code "
                        . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
                        . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)
                        . "</p>";
                    }
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think it is because the period is inside the `"` in the `CREATE TABLE`. That would create an invalid query

Comment: The output of `mysqli_error` is probably giving you a strong hint at the source of the problem.

Comment: did you try `"'".$table_name."'"` ? and try to put space in `TABLE"` I think it also causes error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try echoing $SQLstring and run the query in mysql console. It will point you to the exact problem with your query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify this line to `$SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE" . $TableName . "(BugID SMALLINT` to `$SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE " . $TableName . " (BugID SMALLINT`
2. Instead of checking `$SQLstring = "SHOW TABLES LIKE ' " . $TableName . "' ";` you can check it like `$SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE " . $TableName . " if not exists (BugID SMALLINT`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP, go to localhost/phpmyadmin using your webbrowser.
Select your database, then select sql.

To create your table.

```
CREATE TABLE Bugtrack (
BugID INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Game VARCHAR(10), Version VARCHAR(5),
Platform VARCHAR(10), 
Frequency VARCHAR(5), 
proposed_solution TINYTEXT
)
```

If you really want to do it with php. I would use PDO.

```
$username = 'me';
$password = 'my_super_secret_password';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database';

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE Bugtrack (
BugID INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Game VARCHAR(10), Version VARCHAR(5),
Platform VARCHAR(10), 
Frequency VARCHAR(5), 
proposed_solution TINYTEXT
)';

$conn->execute($sql);
```

OR

Go to localhost/phpmyadmin, click on you database on the left hand side. You will see an option  to create a table. I also would make sure that you have permission for the database that you created. To do that, while you are in phpmyadmin, click your database, select the privileges tab that is almost at the top of the page. From there just follow the prompts.